# How to apply a Binding property to a WPF binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a WPF UserControl. In the cs part, I have a property of type System.Windows.Data.**Binding** called **ElementBinding**.
Here is what the xaml file looks like:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ControlRoot, Path=FilteredSource}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ElementBinding, ElementName=ControlRoot}" />
       </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This doesn't work as intended as it displays (quite logically) the **ToString()** method of the Binding property.
What I would like to do is appy the **Binding** property of my **UserControl** to the **Text** property of my **TextBlock**, using the TextBlock **DataContext**.

I know I can always change my **Binding** property to a **string** property and use a converter and reflection to access the path, but I would prefer with a **Binding** property if it is possible. I guess it is since it's used, for example, in a DataGridColumn.

Comment: What kind of result you currently get displayed in your `<TextBlock/>`? Does it display `Namespace`, empty or an actual value?

Comment: With this, the result is "System.Windows.Data.Binding"

Comment: What is your end requirement ? Text property will of-course display string representation of object.

Comment: Is `ControlRoot.ElementBinding` bound to something? Still it is strange to use `Binding` property for `TextBlock`.

Comment: My end requirement is to set a binding when placing the user control `<c:MyUC ElementBinding="{Binding Path=MyProperty}" />` and apply this binding to the Text property of a TextBlock in a DataTemplate, so that the text property would be [TheTextBlock].DataContext.MyProperty.